# Defining the complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I was pondering a bit about how to define the exponential and trigonometric functions. The definitions I find the most appealing seem to be their definitions as the unique solutions to the ODEs : $y'=y,\ y_0=1$; $y''=-y,\ y_0=0/1$ and $y'_0=1/0$.
However, I was wondering if this could be extended as follows:

$e^z:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is the unique solution to the ODE $\frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb{dz}}f = f$ with $f(0)=1$. Then you define $\cos{x}=\Re(e^{ix})$ and $\sin{x}=\Im(e^{ix})$.

Is there a theorem that allows one to prove the existence of uniqueness in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately not quite, as it only works for real functions - and it focuses on uniqueness, not so much existence

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I wasn't entirely clear. I'm trying to define the exponential as the unique solution to that equation. So I can't assume it exists already

Comment: As an aside, $\Re(e^{ix})$ is not the way to define $\cos x$ for complex $x$. You want $\cos z=(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2$ and $\sin z=(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})/(2i)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Setup

It would be simplest to just write down the Taylor Polynomials and show they converge to a solution, but I assume you want to know how one could approach existence and uniqueness without trying to solve for series coefficients (or already having $e^z$ in hand). So, instead, we can follow similar steps to a [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Detailed_proof) of the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

This answer is heavily inspired by (paraphrasing?) the discussion in "2.3 The Method of Successive Approximations" from [Ordinary Differential Equations in the Complex Domain](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/ordinary-differential-equations-in-the-complex-domain) by Einar Hille, but there is significant simplification in specializing to this case. In other words, I'm not proving the general theorem here, just going through the steps for this ODE.

## Existence

The initial value problem is equivalent to $f(z)=1+\int_0^zf(s)\,\mathrm ds$. Define the sequence of approximations $f_0(z)=1$, $f_n(z)=1+\int_0^zf_{n-1}(s)\,\mathrm ds$. These approximations are all entire (and hence there is no issue with the integrals) because they're all polynomials.

Note that $|f_1(z)-f_0|=|1+z-1|=|z|$. Then $|f_2(z)-f_1(z)|=\left|\int_0^zf_{1}(s)-f_{0}(s)\,\mathrm ds\right|\le\left|\int_0^z|s|\,|\mathrm ds|\right|=\frac12|z|^2$. By an induction argument, we have $|f_k(z)-f_{k-1}(z)|\le|z|^k/k!$ . This means that the series $f(z):=1+\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}\left(f_n(z)-f_{n-1}(z)\right)$ converges absolutely and uniformly on any disk. Since $\lim f_n(z)=f(z)$, this is a solution.

## Uniqueness

Suppose that $g$ is any solution, and define the sequence of $f_n$ as above. Then \begin{align*}|g(z)-f_n(z)|&=\left|\int_0^z g(s)-f_{n-1}(s)\,\mathrm ds\right|\\&\le\left|\int_0^z |g(s)-f_{n-1}(s)|\,|\mathrm ds|\right|\\&\le\left|\int_0^z |\mathrm ds|\left|\int_0^s|g(t)-f_{n-2}(t)|\,|\mathrm dt|\right|\right|\\&=\left|\int_0^z |s||g(s)-f_{n-2}(s)||\mathrm ds|\right|\\\cdots&\le\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\left|\int_0^z |s|^{n-1}|g(s)-1||\mathrm ds|\right|\end{align*}

On any closed disk, $|g(s)-1|$ will be bounded (by $b$, say), so that $|g(z)-f_n(z)|\le b/n!\to0$. Hence $g(z)=f(z)$.

Comment: Ahh I see. So we can find the solution as the limit of those approximating (entire) functions, which is really just the Taylor series in this case, and then uniqueness is shown by how every solution must be the limit of that sequence... Nice!

Comment: @user35013 For this particular ODE, I've really just obscured an argument about the Taylor series, but very similar steps with more constants can show existence and uniqueness on a certain disk of solutions to a class of nice first order ODEs.